# Ordered array connection in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, parsing, hash

I have 3 arrays of the following form:

```
arr1 = [11a,12b,13c,14d,15e,16f]
arr2 = [21g,22h,23i,24j,25k,26l]
arr3 = [31m,31n,32o,32p,33q,34r,35s,36t,36u]
```

You can notice that the first digit in the element number indicates the array number. The second digit is the identifier of the element in the array.

I need to join the elements of these arrays in the following form:

```
11a
21g
31m
31n
12b
22h
32o
32p
13c
23i
33q
14d
24j
34r
15e
25k
35s
16f
26l
36t
36u
```

I'm trying to organize the data by connecting them to one array. I do it this way:

```
res_array=[]
last_element = res3.index(res3.last)
i=-1
loop do
i+=1
res_array<<arr1[i]
res_array<<arr2[i]
res_array<<arr3[i]
break if i >= last_element
end
```

My decision is bad because that I get the data in the wrong form:

```
11a
21g
31m # wrong. lacking 31n
12b
22h
31n # is incorrect. here should be 32o and 32p
13c
23i
32o
14d
24j
32p # is incorrect. there should be 34r
15e
25k
33q # wrong. here should be 35s
16f
26l
34r # wrong. here should be 36t and 36u
35s
36t
36u
```

My code is bad because the elements that start at 3 are not written to the correct blocks.

I think that I need to create an additional loop that will perform res_array << arr3 [i] for elements whose serial number is less than or equal to the sequence number of the previous block.

Comment: Your code is bad because you're using some crazy combination of arrays and strings to represent a complex data type! Define a class for your data, and use proper objects instead.

Comment: _"I need to join the elements ... in the following form"_ – okay, but what are the rules?

Comment: I want to get a few blocks whicj be sorted of block number and position number. The serial number of block is defined by the second digit. The position in the block is determined by the first character. 
For example  "32o" element.
3 - it's position number
2 - it's block number 
o - random text

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
[*arr1, *arr2, *arr3].sort_by { |item| [item[1], item[-1], item[0]]  }
[
    [ 0] "11a",
    [ 1] "21g",
    [ 2] "31m",
    [ 3] "31n",
    [ 4] "12b",
    [ 5] "22h",
    [ 6] "32o",
    [ 7] "32p",
    [ 8] "13c",
    [ 9] "23i",
    [10] "33q",
    [11] "14d",
    [12] "24j",
    [13] "34r",
    [14] "15e",
    [15] "25k",
    [16] "35s",
    [17] "16f",
    [18] "26l",
    [19] "36t",
    [20] "36u"
]
```